# Opening a view after launching in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to have a view open programatically at the end of an eclipse ILaunchConfigurationDelegate.  Currently I'm getting an "invalid thread access" error when I try to call showView().  How do I open a view from the launcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your call like this;

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Your code goes here
  }
});
```

This will put it on the Display thread and should fix the errors your seeing.

Comment: Thanks! That held me up for a week.